Hazelcast and TLS
We are willing to upgrade from Hazelcast version 3.12.13 to version 5.3. Everything is working fine in 3.12.13 but when we move to 5.3 we get an error in our application:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Hazelcast is the only thing we changed. We have used as little options from Hazelcast as we could, it basically serves to communicate between two or three machines. The machines are using mTLS (mutual TLS) to talk to other machines. Nothing TLS like is configured for Hazelcast itself to talk to the members of the cluster.
Any ideas where this error comes from and how we can avoid it?
